# python and MySQL connectivity isn't updating

Tags: python, mysql

i have this code here that every second runs a SELECT query on the MySQL table.
i see the change in the MySQL table but the value returning from the query isn't changing. do i need to refresh the connectivity somehow?

```
while (flag==0 and count<30):
    for x in user_id_arr:
            cur.execute("SELECT status FROM user_locations WHERE user_id = %d" % (x))
            res = cur.fetchall()
            print res
            resp_arr = resp_arr + [res[0][0]]
            res = None

    print resp_arr

    if (resp_arr==["accepted","accepted"]):
            print "Everyone Accepted"
            for x in user_id_arr:
                    cur.execute("UPDATE user_locations SET status = 'going'  WHERE user_id = %d" % (x))
                    db.commit()
            flag=1
    else:
            print "Not everyone accepted"
            resp_arr = []
            res = 0
    time.sleep(1)
    count +=1
```

(the prints are for debugging)

Answer (score 0):

I was about to give up finding your problem but think I might have it!

```
while (flag==0 and count<30):
    for x in user_id_arr:
            cur.execute("SELECT status FROM user_locations WHERE user_id = %d" % (x))
            res = cur.fetchall()
            print res
            resp_arr = resp_arr + [res[0][0]]
            res = None

    print resp_arr

    if (resp_arr==["accepted","accepted"]):
            print "Everyone Accepted"
            for x in user_id_arr:
                    cur.execute("UPDATE user_locations SET status = 'going'  WHERE user_id = %d" % (x))
                    db.commit()
            flag=1
```

It's basically indenting.

Your top loop cycles through the user_id_arr but then keeps only the very last x value and goes onto the if statement. You need to fix the way your control structures are indenting, and set up, so that that second loop down there is part of the initial loop, and the if statement indented within it.

Probably like this:

```
while (flag==0 and count<30):
    for x in user_id_arr:
            cur.execute("SELECT status FROM user_locations WHERE user_id = %d" % (x))
            res = cur.fetchall()
            print res
            resp_arr = resp_arr + [res[0][0]]
            res = None

            print resp_arr

            if (resp_arr==["accepted","accepted"]):
                 print "Everyone Accepted"
                 cur.execute("UPDATE user_locations SET status = 'going'  WHERE user_id = %d" % (x))
                 db.commit()
                 flag=1
            else:
                print "Not everyone accepted"
                resp_arr = []
                res = 0
            time.sleep(1)
            count +=1
```

Answer (score -1):

because i'm using the mysqldb library there is no refresh option but i found out using db.commit() can cause a refresh and thus solving my problem.